# Are questions asking for worldbuilding related terminology on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/is-there-any-kind-of-technical-term-for-a-civilization-that-eats-others-to-gai) asks for a term describing a civilization that eats others to gain their assets. It's an interesting question and clearly related to worldbuilding. I would argue that worldbuilding is not the best fit for this question though and I think it would do better on either [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).

The way I see it, this is not a question about worldbuilding, but rather a question related to worldbuilding. I suppose it's up to the community to decide if questions like these should be within the scope of this site.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there is a massive grey area here and some "name this" questions may well be on topic but others not.

For example a parasitic society that preys on others is clearly on topic, so naming of it should also be on topic.

Football is clearly off topic, so naming of it is also off topic.

Football in space? Football with quadruped aliens? That's now on topic - so naming of the new sport is on topic.

So my suggestion is that if the subject that the naming question is about is on topic then naming questions are on topic, and not otherwise. Especially since some naming questions might not be on topic on another site. For example English Language is unlikely to care about made-up names but actually you can construct a word such as "sociovore" for something that eats society so it's not just a matter of picking a bunch of random syllables.

Comment: The question clearly asks for an already existing term though. I'd be mnore inclined to call it on topic if it was looking to come up with a term that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: It's SOCCER you damn Yankee!

Answer (score 2):

This question is on topic because it related directly to world building.

I think Sci-fi or English Language would give you better answers however (especially Sci-fi for this question)

Edit: Just don't post it to everything.

Comment: I agree. Just because a question might be on topic on another site doesn't make it off topic here. English Language might be able to tell you if a word exists but if you needed to create a word I don't know how helpful they would be there.

Answer (score 1):

This question is off topic beacuse the answers won't relate directly to world building and more than the answers to the question: "What do you call a game where 22 people kick around a ball?" would. Even if you intend to have a fictional species play football in your book.

Furthermore, this question would generate better answers on other sites in the stack exchange network, it is therefore unnecessary to include it in the scope of this site.