# Opinion based, list questions?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/is-there-any-kind-of-technical-term-for-a-civilization-that-eats-others-to-gai) has so far attracted a higher than usual number of answers, most of which could be construed as opinion-based, and together looking like a list question.

Mind you, I'm not saying that's necessarily a bad thing. Although most SEs avoid such questions, some (notably ELU's word/phrase-request questions) actively embrace them. Do we want specific policies around such questions - welcome or avoid - or is the default voting mechanism enough? Does the [back-it-up policy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/back-it-up-policies) sufficiently cover questions such as this?

Related discussion about the question itself being a terminology-request question: [Are questions asking for worldbuilding related terminology on topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/are-questions-asking-for-worldbuilding-related-terminology-on-topic)

Comment: Relevant to the List part: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/110/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes, because they won't be welcome on other sites and they are about world-building. I certainly think the community can handle them.

These questions could also be very hard to answer on your own/with google searches.

Comment: While I agree with parts of this answer, I have to disagree with "because they won't be welcome on other sites" being part of the reason why we should accept the question, even as a qualifier. It implies that we should accept questions more readily if they have no overlap, which is not what you intended to say, I'm sure.

Comment: @Mourdos If the question is a slightly questionable fit for this site, but readily welcomed on another site, then we should probably try to forward it to the other site (though we could try to answer it here). But if it isn't answerable on another site, and it is answerable here, then it makes it clearer that it should be here. Overlap is ok, but it can make things slightly confusing.